# Convergence of $\sum \sin\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\quad p>1$$

My attempt:

---

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\sin\frac{1}{n^p} $$

And

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges if
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin\frac{1}{n^p}|$ converges, but

$|\sin\frac{1}{n^p}| < |\frac{1}{n^p}|$ and the right hand term is a p-series which we know converges and moreover both terms are positive so the sum converges absolutely and therefore converges.

Then we see that for $n$ large enough $\frac{1}{n^p}$ will be between $0$ and $\pi/2$ where $\sin(1/n^p)$ is from there onwards decreasing and its limit clearly goes to $0$ so by the alternating series test the sum  converges.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense. This series can be shown to be convergent both with the alternating series test and the absolute convergence test.

Comment: The alternating series test is too big a hammer for $p>1$ but one would appeal to it to show (non absolute) convergence for $0<p\leqslant1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both of your solutions are correct. I would just note that you missed a $(-1)^n$ in the expression after the "And" -- actually, maybe that's what you intended, but it's easier to just write $|(-1)^n \sin x| = |\sin x|$. Also there's no need for $n$ to be "large enough" in the last paragraph because the first term is already $1 < \pi/2$.

Here's a bonus problem for you: Can we weaken the restriction on $p$? That is, find all values of $p$ for which the series converges.

Comment: guestDiego, that is not correct. You cannot conclude that your $R$ is divergent from the fact that the upper bound you have selected for it is divergent.

Comment: You are riight. I will correct it

Comment: Thanks to the correction of  Yakov Shklarov, I restate my guess sayng that since the Taylor expansion of $\sin$ has only odd terms, then the series converge for any $p>0$: My proposal: if $a_n=(-1)^n n^{-p}$, then  $ \sum_n a_n=\sum_n (-1)^n(\sum_{k=1}^{K}n^{-pk}/k!+O(n^{-p(K+1)}))$, where $(K+1)p>1$. The first $K$ series converge by the theorem about the alternate-sign series. The last series converges absolutely.

Comment: Corrige: $a_n=(-1)^n n^{-p}$ has to be replaced by $a_n=\sin((-1)^n n^{-p})$

Answer (score 0):

One knows by the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ that
$$
sin(x)=x+R(x),\quad |R(x)|\leq x^3
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} R((-1)^n n^{-p})
$$
The first series is convergent since it is a series of alternating sign terms  with modulus tending monotonically to zero. The second series is absolutely convergent, since:
$$
|R((-1)^n n^{-p})|\leq n^{-2p}, \quad p>1
$$